# When I run The Junit Test

Tags: java

Java is a programming language that produces software for multiple platforms. When a programmer writes a Java application, the compiled code (known as bytecode) runs on most operating systems (OS), including Windows, Linux and Mac OS?

```
package org.com.support.boot.org.com.support.boot;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.com.support.boot.models.Student;
import org.com.support.boot.repos.StudentRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringdatajpaApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveStudent() {

        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.setId(1);
        newStudent.setName("Mirza");
        newStudent.setTestScore(23);

        repository.save(newStudent);

        Student student = repository.findById(1);

        assertNotNull(student);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateStudent() {

        Student updateStudent = new Student();
        updateStudent.setId(1);
        updateStudent.setName("Mirza");
        updateStudent.setTestScore(51);

        repository.save(updateStudent);

        Student student = repository.findById(1);

        assertEquals(51, student.getTestScore());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeletStudent() {

        Student deleteStudent = new Student();
        deleteStudent.setId(1);
        deleteStudent.setName("Mirza");
        deleteStudent.setTestScore(51);

        repository.delete(deleteStudent);
        Student student = repository.findById(1);
        assertNull(student);
    }

}
```

Comment: Voting to close this question. Totally unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The compiled byte code will run on any JVM of a sufficiently high version, regardless of the platform running it.

Note, however, that the code itself may make assumptions about the platform (e.g., the code could assume you have a `c:` drive, which is only correct in Windows) which the JVM won't magically fix for you.